# Search Results Bulk Actions in Faceted Search screen in 5.1.1

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We need to customize results datatable with searching results. We need to add checkbox to each row and perform bulk actions upon selected nodes (e.g. Download As Zip, Edit Properties etc.). 
We are using Alfresco Enterprise 5.1.1 & aikau-1.0.67.1.

I see there is external JIRA issue going on for this specific issue.As per jira ,I think these actions have been applied in 5.2 version.How to apply this functionality in 5.1.1 version.

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/SHA-1439

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the bulk actions working for the faceted search page it is necessary to update the search REST APIs to return **all** the metadata for the nodes. In 5.1 and earlier only a subset of metadata was being returned, and this does not include the permissions and aspects data that is required to determine whether or not an action can be applied to the search results that have been selected.

Therefore in order to get this working it will be necessary to update the search.lib.js file (in the Share Services AMP) to add in the extra metadata. This will need to be done in each of the functions specific to each node type (getDocumentItem, getBlogPostItem, getForumPostItem, etc. etc.). You will need to add the entry:

```
nodeJSON: appUtils.toJSON(node, true)
```

...into each item object that is created. This will then ensure all the metadata is available.

At this point you can then look to add in the Aikau widgets to the search page to support bulk action handling.

Given that Aikau is open source you can essentially just review the changes in the faceted-search.get.js file.

You'll also need a more recent version of Aikau than the one provided with 5.1

Comment: I am newbie to Aikau.I have done only small examples.can you give some idea on how to achieve this Bulk operations functionality in Search screen.

Comment: With the greatest of respect, that is what my existing answer does. If you would like to get bulk actions in search with the least amount of effort then you may want to wait for the 5.2 release of Alfresco (an EA is available now: https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6467-alfresco-community-edition-201611-ea-release-notes)